# The cardinal number

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $c$ be the cardinal number of $[0,1]$, i.e. $|[0,1]|=c$. Notice that $|A|\cdot|B| = |A\times B|$ and $|\mathbb{R}| = c$. Prove that $c\cdot c=c$. Don't use $ab=\max\{a,b\}$ where $a,b$ are infinite.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: First I showed that $|\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}|$ to show  $cc=c$. But now I think it is not easy to show that $|\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}|$. This is not my home work.

Comment: You can edit the question to improve it in several ways. First, it is not clear why you are asking a question and then telling other people how to solve it (e.g. "Don't use ..."). Did the question come from somewhere else - if so, what was the sources? Second, what have you tried already?  In its current form, whether the question is homework or not, it looks exactly like a homework problem that has been copied onto this site.

Comment: In particular, do you know any other sets of cardinality $c$?

Comment: I want to prove it by without $ab=\max\{a,b\}$.

Comment: For example, I can prove $\aleph_0 \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$  not use $ab=\max\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Convenient ways to proceed depend a bit on what you already know. For instance, if you know $|R|=2^{\aleph_0}$, then you easily get $|R \times R|=2^{\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0}$, which reduces the problem to showing $\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$.

Comment: @ lan  Thank you so much gave me idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach you can take. For every $x\in(0,1],$ show that there is a unique sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ such that every $a_n\in\{0,1\},$ there are infinitely-many $a_n=1,$ and $$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{2^n}.$$ Use this to show that the set $S$ of all such sequences together with the sequence of all $0$s, has the same cardinality as $[0,1].$ Then, given an ordered pair of two sequences of $S$--say $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots$--we create another such sequence by interleaving them as $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots.$ Use this to show that $S\times S$ is in bijection with $S,$ whence $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is in bijection with $[0,1].$